# Focus effect on HTML <li>tag ( Wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, content-management-system, html-lists, elementor

Is there any way with css or JavaScript to set an animation border when it is clicked or active in wordpress?

I want to make this effect on a ul lists.I'm using a filter product and i can't put a button inside li elements.

```css
.btn{
  border:none;
  color: #FFFFFF29;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  font-size:65px;
  transition: .3s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.btn::before{
   content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: translateX(-105%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;


}

.btn:focus::before{
   transform: translateX(0);
}

.btn:focus{
  transition:.3s;
  color:#fff;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;

}
.btn:not(hover){
    color: #FFFFFF29 ;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
ul {
     background-color:#1a1a1a;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
    <li><button class="btn" >Digital Marketing</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn" >Sviluppo</button></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Can you make your question clear? What do you mean by 'animation border'

Comment: i’m looking for a way to  put focus on a li item.But I can’t do that in html since  the list items are taken from a filter plugin in WordPress so I can only edit css and js

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn:not(hover){
    color: var(--e-global-color-secondary) !important;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Elementor Class Add into a tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfiSm.gif)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).